# Disabling Wireless on Windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

On a Windows 10 laptop, what is the best way to disable wireless connections, so that I know I'm connected to a network only when my Ethernet cable is plugged in?

I realize that joining a network requires manual initiation, but I'm seeking a stronger, more secure solution than just not joining, to prevent joining by fluke.  Is there, i.e., a set of service(s) that can be disabled or a set of driver(s) that can be uninstalled to achieve this goal?

Comment: Why can’t you just disable the adapter in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `network`, open **network status**.
- Click on
  **change adaptor options**
- Select your adapter, right-click and choose **deactivate**.

[image: Netzwerkadapter deaktivieren]

Comment: Translated to english, My windows instance is acting a bit strange so I'll leave the screenshots as is